# In how many different ways can $7$ identical objects be distributed between $3$ ordered boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Why is this a permutation and not a combination?

I have the solution for the following question. The problem I am experiencing is I do not understand how the answer is found.

The question as follows:

> In how many different ways can $7$ identical objects be distributed between $3$ ordered boxes, box 1, box 2 and box 3? For how many of these distributions is there at least one object in each box?

The solution I have finds the following first:
$$\binom92 = 36$$

However, when I put this into the calculator I get an answer of $18$

The final answer is: $$\binom62 = 15$$

When I also put the above into the calculator I get $12$...

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Do you understand how $\binom{9}{2}$ and $\binom{6}{2}$ were obtained?  What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions are correct and the numbers you got are not that of the corresponding $^nP_r$ since generally $^nP_r\ge \ ^nC_r$. It seems like you got $$9\times2=18$$and$$6\times2=12$$
instead of the correct answers.

Note that
$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

Comment: Thanks, that made it a lot clearer